# Strange behavior of time in Java

Tags: java, date, time

I have a very strange problem. I wrote the following code:

```
public static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MS = 86400000L;

public static long getTimeOfTheDayInMs() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() % ONE_DAY_IN_MS;
}
```

This should return the milliseconds since midnight, right?
Well, yes and no, since it returns the time since midnight **less one hour**.
Why is that? Why this code:

```
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println(new Date(getTimeOfTheDayInMs()));
```

returns this??

```
18-jul-2013 12.34.03
1-jan-1970 11.34.03
```

I also discovered that this issue seems to appear from 30 March 1992.

Has anyone else the same problem as mine? Can someone explain me why?

Thanks in advance,

PS: This issue appears me both in my Windows PC and in my Android tablet.

Comment: Have you taken into account daylight savings time?

Comment: Have you taken into account the time zone? Use a Calendar (or a 3rd party API like Joda Dates) for that

Comment: Hi! Actually, you're right, I haven't. How can I do it?

Comment: My crystal ball is telling me that you're looking for the wrong result. Are you sure you want the number of ms since midnight? What are you going to use that number for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getTimeOfTheDayInMs()` does *not* return the milliseconds since midnight. The epoch is 1970 and `currentTimeMillis()` is relative to that. Use `Calendar` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html for getting second etc fields.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I get

```
Thu Jul 18 12:33:53 CEST 2013
Thu Jan 01 11:33:53 CET 1970
```

i.e. the difference is the summer-time shift (CEST is central european summer time; CET is central european (winter) time i.e. GMT + 1).

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of time-zone changes, changes in daylight saving time polices etc.
I strongly advise you against using Date class in production code. Use Calendar or even better Joda Time.

```
  DateMidnight midnight = new DateMidnight();
  DateTime now = new DateTime();
  Duration duration = new Duration(midnight, now);
  int seconds = duration.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds();
```